# Div will not expand properly

Tags: css, html

I have a page that I am trying to create with a div on the left containing an iframe and a div in the middle also containing an iframe.

The sidebar is to hold links and the content section is to load said links.

My goal is to get the sidebar expanded all the way down to the bottom of the page as well as the content section.

Here is my css:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#pdfholder {
    float: right;
width: 600px;
}
```

And here is my html:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <iframe id="sidebarframe" name="index" src="./sidebar.html">
            </iframe>
        </div>

        <div id="pdfholder">
            <iframe id="pdfholderframe" name="viewer" src="./blank.html">
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I know I am doing something wrong but I have gone through around 10 different websites and I cannot for the life of me find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give both containing divs a min-height of 100% and there's not much more you need to do: 
http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/eHMec/

You can give the iframes a height of 100% too, but it didn't become clear to me whether you need that or not.

Comment: Well I need the iFrame in the content area (it is holding pdf files) and as for the sidebar.. I just need a place to put links that are held in another file (I have a python script that scans a directory for files and loads the file names into the other file).

I have done server side includes, but that is.. Ok. I need to look at frames more either way. But any other suggestion for placing the sidebar?

Comment: I have tried out your css and html and it seemed to work well. But there is a tiny margin at the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/mitsu400/E6vP3/

I had this problem before and I can't remember how to fix it...

Comment: I don't see the marging in that fiddle (Chrome). Except for the border. I gave the divs a border for the demonstration, but since the width of 100% is set on the inner area only, they really shouldn't have a border. Any border, padding and margin make those divs larger than 100%

Comment: Maybe you should check the HTML5 `seamless` attribute for iframes. http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_iframe_tag.cfm

Comment: Sorry for not getting back sooner. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mitsu400/QtUZr/) is what I ended up doing. I just got rid of the divs holding the iframes and just styled the iframes on their own. By the way, I just chose two sites at random that I knew would fit in the two frames without much overflow. Either way. Thanks for the suggestions!!

Comment: For the demo it may not have been a good thing to use a site that forces a refresh to get out of the iframe. :D

Comment: Just as easy. Anyway, the seamless attribute did the trick, I see? :)

Comment: Man sorry for not getting back sooner.. I totally forgot about this question. But yes it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your question, [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Swpbv/) ([simpler version here](http://jsfiddle.net/7nE9Q/)) should do the trick.

#### CSS

```
div
{
    background: black;
}

div div
{
    margin-left: 150px;
    background: white;
}

div ul
{
   float: left;
    color: white;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Nav bar</li>
        <li>More nav</li>
    </ul>

    <div>
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously this is a very simple example and you should give your elements classes or IDs if needbe; I wanted to keep it simple.

The principle of this is a `float: left`, a `margin-left: 150px` and some `background-color` properties. You give your container `div` a background colour of whatever you want the sidebar to be coloured as, and then set the content `div`s background back to white, or whatever you want *that* to be.

The `float: left` for the navbar `ul` means the main content is pushed back to the top.

The `margin-left: 150px` gives the navbar 150px on the left of the content to expand into. Obviously you should change this to the width of the navbar.